# What should I do after defeating all these bosses?

Tags: terraria-mobile

I'm playing Terraria on my iPad and I'm at a bit of a loss as to where I go from here.

In terms of equipment, I have shadow helmet/scalemail/greaves, as well as weapons such as Phoenix Blaster Slow Starfury, Breaker Blade.

I have defeated, eye of Cthulhu, Eater of Worlds, Brain of Cthulhu, Skeltron, goblin army (many times) and the wall of flesh.

Where do I go from here? What can I do now?

Comment: Ehmm, This is strange, I take it that you're already on hard mode, why are you looking for stuff to do? There are tons of things to do once you're there, improving that armor would be an example. Not sure what are you asking for.

Answer (score 1):

Use the pwnhammer to break demon alters,
this will cause some hardmode ores to spawn
on your world,
 mine them to make better gear,
fight some mechanical bosses,
(for info on how to summon them see [terraria wiki](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Terraria_Wiki))
Kill planterra (again, visit the wiki),
Farm the dungeon for ectoplasm and try to fight the waves.

Note: not sure how much of this is relevant to pocket edition,
Please edit out anything you're sure isn't.

Answer (score -3):

You should improve your armor like the other user said, and fight the final boss of mobile Terraria at the moment (golem). There are a lot things you can do once you're on hard mode; also more deaths can happen, so be careful.